# Single wire earth return system

Tags: grounding, transmission-line, earth

So, in a single wire transmission system, the earth acts as the return path for current to "flow back to source". Would this work for anywhere on earth, say, if we transmit current on a single wire from Paris to Los Angeles, ignoring the voltage drop on the long transmission wire.

Comment: Anything will work if you ignore the things that prevent them from working.

Comment: I'm only ignoring the transmission wire resistance, not the properties of earth.

Comment: The distance and terrain make the wire connection impossible. The distance likely more than doubles the impossibility even though close to half the shortest route is saltwater.

Comment: Paris to Los Angeles not currently feasible. There is a 12GW HVDC link long enough to cover Shannon to Gander - roughly the shortest route across the Atlantic. (But it includes  its own return). So ,wait a few years.

Comment: Well, my question was - would the "earth" still work as a return path?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a hypothetical question with no real world application.

Comment: If the voltage drop caused by the current doesn't bother you it would surely work.

Comment: Well, I have been watching 'videos on grounding' of Mike Holt lately, and it seems that it WON'T WORK. Feels like I know nothing about earth wire at all.

https://www.youtube.com/user/MikeHoltNEC